# is it safe to allow clients to connect directly to a rabbitmq and consume a queue?

Tags: rabbitmq

I need to create a service that will send forex prices to thousands of connected clients. I'm thinking that i can use rabbitmq fanout exchange for this and clients can subscribe to the instruments they are interested in. My question is, would it be safe to have a client application connect directly to rabbitmq? or is it a better decision to manage the connection to rabbitmq from a custom tcpserver application and have clients connect through my tcpserver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a very specific reason (for instance, you want a load balancer in front of a RabbitMQ cluster), there's no reason to (reverse) proxy RabbitMQ.

In addition, trying to manage the connection through am application would raise quite a few problems.  For instance, 2.0.0 uses TCP back-pressure in order to throttle clients; you'd have to handle this somehow.

Comment: But would there be any security implications to exposing rabbitmq like that?

Comment: RabbitMQ itself is fairly secure.  It does provide a password-based login system.  On top of that, you can use SSL to ensure the identity of the clients and to encrypt the connection.